# Ternary that I am trying to check strings in one line rather than separate it to multiple

Tags: reactjs

is there a way to have the Leases.ProgramBucket reduced to something more like Leases.ProgramBucket === 'B' || 'C' || 'SU' instead of having it need to be on its own to help reduce the amount of redundancy within all of this just to check if its a B, C, or SU?

I am pulling these from an SQL database and this does currently work but the ProgramBucket is the only one that has a difference as the date range remains the same no matter just want to shorten the ProgramBucket and what it possibly can be I have also tried it with the && but they can't have both || and &&. this is a simple string not an array as it is pulling from tables and a person could be assigned any of the 3 B, C, SU.

```
<tr>
                  {Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && Leases.ProgramBucket === 'B' ? <td>{Leases.LeaseNumber}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
                  {Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && Leases.ProgramBucket === 'B' ? <td>{Leases.LeaseName}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
                  {Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && Leases.ProgramBucket === 'B' ? <td>{Leases.DaysPastDue}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
                  {Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && Leases.ProgramBucket === 'B' ? <td>{Leases.AmountPastDue}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
                  {Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && Leases.ProgramBucket === 'B' ? <td>{Leases.ProgramBucket}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  {Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && Leases.ProgramBucket === 'C' ? <td>{Leases.LeaseNumber}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
                  {Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && Leases.ProgramBucket === 'C' ? <td>{Leases.LeaseName}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
                  {Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && Leases.ProgramBucket === 'C' ? <td>{Leases.DaysPastDue}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
                  {Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && Leases.ProgramBucket === 'C' ? <td>{Leases.AmountPastDue}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
                  {Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && Leases.ProgramBucket === 'C' ? <td>{Leases.ProgramBucket}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  {Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && Leases.ProgramBucket === 'SU' ? <td>{Leases.LeaseNumber}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
                  {Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && Leases.ProgramBucket === 'SU' ? <td>{Leases.LeaseName}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
                  {Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && Leases.ProgramBucket === 'SU' ? <td>{Leases.DaysPastDue}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
                  {Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && Leases.ProgramBucket === 'SU' ? <td>{Leases.AmountPastDue}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
                  {Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && Leases.ProgramBucket === 'SU' ? <td>{Leases.ProgramBucket}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
              </tr>
```

Comment: `if(['B','C','SU'].includes(Leases.ProgramBucket)) {doSomeWork();}`

Comment: That seems to have gotten it I have it written like so and working well
```{Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && (['B','C','SU'].includes(Leases.ProgramBucket)) ? <td>{Leases.LeaseNumber}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}```

Answer (score 0):

I have it written like so and it is now working well

```
{Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && (['B','C','SU'].includes(Leases.ProgramBucket)) ? <td>{Leases.LeaseNumber}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}
```

Comment: Good, but why do you have 5 exact blocks of `<td>`? Maybe you want to shortcut them all even more?

Comment: each one displays a different item in the table like the lease number, the lease name, how many days past due, amount past due, and the credit type. Then I have to have it for 2 different companies and will have more for different DaysPastDue like 31+ and 1-45 and 45+ it was that I had to have the B, C, SU like my original for two companies so double it even more and now I just have 10 line rather than 30. I am willing to reduce the amount more if you know how?

Comment: Some inspiration to you on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-framework-f7r6yg?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you for that I will have to incorporate that into mine. Mind helping me on instead of showing each listed it shows a count of how many are under 30 days so the sandbox would just show the number 2 and the other a 1?

Comment: Sure, updated the codesandbox.

Comment: How would it look for the old way ```{Leases.DaysPastDue <= 30 && (['B','C','SU'].includes(Leases.ProgramBucket)) ? <td>{Leases.LeaseNumber}</td> : <td className='hide'></td>}``` I am currently writing the new way now to work with the Database as it needs to pull the code so need to alter mine to work properly.

Comment: Sorry, was away and still away, but you really should prepare a new questions with information about what you have and what you want to achieve, also about what you tried to do to achieve that, community will help you. But general recommendation - do a little decomposition of your UI components, do data preparation logic in useState/useMemo/useEffect, and map prepared data. React is much simpler and sleeker than you think